# Firebase won't let me add new fields

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an android app with java language and I am using firebase for data storage. It was working fine previously but recently I added new fields in a document. I am getting real time updates on that document through snapshot listener. But when I try to get new fields from the `DocumentSnapshot` object, it returns null. Only for the new fields. Note that I didn't physically added the fields directly in the database. I have only modified the code in snapshot listener to get those fields as well. Also the document is not present initially and yet the `doc.exists()` returns true.
Here is the code of snapshot listener. What am I doing wrong?

```
public LiveData<List<Booking>> getBookingsDataWithIds(List<String> bookingIds){
    if(clientBookings.getValue()==null && bookingIds.size()>0){

       db.collection("Bookings").whereIn("Booking-ID",bookingIds).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
           @Override
           public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
               if(error!=null){
                   Log.e("BOOKINGS ERROR: ",error.getMessage());
               }
               if(value!=null){
                   List<DocumentSnapshot> docs=value.getDocuments();
                   bookings=new ArrayList<>();
                   for(DocumentSnapshot doc : docs){
                       if(!doc.exists())
                           continue;
                       bookings.add(new Booking(doc.getId(),
                               doc.get("Status").toString(),
                               doc.get("Service Station").toString(),
                               doc.get("Client Name").toString(),
                               doc.get("Client Phone").toString(),
                               doc.get("Client Email").toString(),
                               (Double)doc.get("Lat"),
                               (Double)doc.get("Lng"),
                               doc.get("Vehicle Name").toString(),
                               doc.get("Vehicle Type").toString(),
                               doc.get("Date").toString(),
                               doc.get("Time").toString(),
                               doc.get("Admin Email").toString(),
                               doc.get("Payment Status").toString(),
                               doc.get("Payment Date").toString(),
                               doc.get("Payment Time").toString(),
                               (Integer) doc.get("Payment Charges"),
                               (Integer)doc.get("Payment Tip")));
                   }
                   clientBookings.postValue(bookings);
               }
               else{
                   Log.e("BOOKINGS ERROR:","value is null");
               }
           }
       });
    }
    return clientBookings;
}
```

Comment: If the new properties didn't exist earlier, I good approach would be to always check against nullity when try to reading them.

Comment: @AlexMamo Yeah that's actually more fine approach. I solved it though but I passed null in the arguments in place of new fields initially and added data through app in the "Bookings" collection and then just added those new fields back in the code :D. It worked but your approach is more neat. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear that. You're welcome ;)

Comment: @TahaKZed would you mind creating a reply with the solution you found?

Comment: @Roger sorry for late reply. I just added the solution as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I solved it by removing the code to fetch the newly added fields. Then I ran the app once and re added the code to fetch those fields. For example, in my code, lets say the field 'Payment Status' is the new field I added to firebase. So now I wanted to fetch that field. but initially I couldn't do that because it showed me error so I removed/commented the code `doc.get("Payment Status")` and ran the app. Then I re-added this line and ran it again and it worked fine.